# Foundation 6 resize and centering issues

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

Hello Im having problems with foundation 6. In my footer there is a social list with 4 icons(phone, email, twitter, facebook) I cant get them to stay centered on resize. On my PC it seems fine, however, uploaded onto the web and viewed on my phone(nexus 6) the icons are off center to the left. here is my footer code

```
<footer>
    <!--social icons should be centered -->
    <div class="row">        
        <div class="large-3 medium-centered columns">
            <ul class="menu social">
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.twitter.com">
                        <i class="fi-social-twitter"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
                        <i class="fi-social-facebook"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>  
                <li>
                    <a href="tel:12345678901 ;="">
                        <i class="fi-telephone"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="mailto:info@example.com">
                        <i class="fi-mail"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>     
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>         
    <p class="text-center copyright"> All Rights Reserved Final FInal 2016.</p>
</footer>
```

The site is www.gastromob.com. I could really use some suggestions on how to improve this site. I'm having several problems, but I'd like to fix this one first, thanks.

Comment: use Bootstrap ....   http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: I'm using foundation, redoing the site in bootstrap isn't a solution.

Comment: Don't listen to the Bootstrap fanboys. Foundation is freaking awesome and way less bloat. Anyhow, what version are you using? I've not seen "medium-centered" as a class before and is the ul even necessary? I'm guessing (since I can't see the whole layout) but it's just a class issue. Oh and PS, your actual layout doesn't reflect what you've posted here. Honestly it looks like you just jacked someones template but aren't quite sure what you're doing now, sorry amigo.

Answer (score 0):

The class `medium-centered` that you use is meant to center a column within a row; it does not center the text inside that column.

Foundation 6 recommends using the `<div class="menu-centered">` wrapper around the `<ul class="menu">`. If you're using Flexbox, you don't need the wrapper and can add the `.align-center` class to the `ul` element instead. Please click [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/menu.html#item-alignment) for more information.

Using the `row` and `column` wrapper seems unnecessary here.

You could write your code this way to achieve what you need:

```
<footer>
  <div class="menu-centered">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com">
          <i class="fi-social-twitter"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
          <i class="fi-social-facebook"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="tel:12345678901">
          <i class="fi-telephone"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="mailto:info@example.com">
          <i class="fi-mail"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p class="text-center copyright"> All Rights Reserved Final FInal 2016.</p>
</footer>
```

By the way, `href="tel:12345678901 ;=""` is incorrect and should be `href="tel:1234567890"` instead.

I've also looked at your site, and noticed that you set a fixed height for the element `<div id="overlay">`. As a result, when viewing the site on a small device, this overlay spills over and covers the elements below it. You should simply remove the fixed height to solve this problem.

The boat logo also obstructs the view when shrinking the size of the screen. You may want to make it responsive as well.

Other than that, all the other elements are responsive and look good!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I fixed that issue. Still stuck on header. I cannot get elements to center correctly. Any suggestions on how to make this work? I want the logo and title to be centered along with the headline and button.. On mobile I want only the title and button to be displayed, centered. Right now on both computer and mobile the title is off center. I keep trying different columns, nav-bar ideas, but so far nothing is working the way I want. Please help!! website is www.gastromob.com

Comment: I think the problem is that you seem to really like using `position: relative`. You may want to watch the video at http://cssreset.com/understanding-css-relative-and-absolute-positioning-explained/ to understand CSS positioning better. I used this code to align the header: `<div class="large-5 large-centered columns theLogo"><h1 class="logotext"><img src="assets/images/client_logo_1.png"> The Client </h1></div>`. You'll also need to add `text-align: center` to `.theLogo` class. And remove `position: relative` from all classes used in the header. They are not necessary.